# Grouping by date period name in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, group-by

I have table with DateTime? column 'DueOn'. And I am trying to group all rows by this column.

```
 var groupBy = new Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime?>>(t => t.DueOn);
 var groups = sequence.GroupBy(groupBy).ToList();
```

All works fine. But I would like to groups in form of:

Yesterday
Today
Tomorrow
Someday if nullable

One way i see is to loop through list from result, compare DueOn and copy items to another list with mentioned above groups.

But maybe there is more efficient solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this : `var groups = sequence.GroupBy(groupBy).Orderby(groupBy).ToList();`

Comment: Do the dates only contain Yesterday, Today and Tomorrow and nulls?

Comment: Nope there are dates from the Past which i want to call Overdue, and dates in the future. I just gave 4 examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating an explicit expression object, a way to group dates in predetermined time buckets is this:

```
dates.GroupBy(da => da.HasValue
                    ? da.Value.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
                        ? "Future"
                        : da.Value.Date > DateTime.Today
                            ? "Tomorrow" 
                            :  da.Value.Date == DateTime.Today
                                ? "Today" 
                                : da.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
                                    ? "Yesterday"
                                    : "Overdue"
                    : "Some day")
```

Of course you can store the entire expression in the `groupBy` variable.